# Ag Grid React checkboxSelection: true is not allowing select/unselect row when using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid-react

I am new to Ag grid and want to create a tabular structure with checkbox selection. This is the way I am using Ag grid React for creating table

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

export const GridExample = () => {
    const data = {
        columnDefs: [
            {
                headerName: 'Athlete',
                field: 'athlete',
                minWidth: 180,
                headerCheckboxSelection: true,
                checkboxSelection: true,
            },
            { field: 'age' },
            {
                field: 'country',
                minWidth: 150,
            },
            { field: 'year' },
            {
                field: 'date',
                minWidth: 150,
            },
            {
                field: 'sport',
                minWidth: 150,
            },
            { field: 'gold' },
            { field: 'silver' },
            { field: 'bronze' },
            { field: 'total' },
        ],
        defaultColDef: {
            flex: 1,
            minWidth: 100,
            resizable: true,
        },
        rowSelection: 'multiple',
        rowData: [],
    };
    const [columnData, setColumnData] = useState(data.columnDefs)
    const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(data.rowData)
    const [defaultColData, setDefaultColData] = useState(data.defaultColDef)
    const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState(data.rowSelection)


    const onGridReady = (params: any) => {
        const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const updateData = (data: any) => {
            setRowData(data);
        };

        httpRequest.open(
            'GET',
            'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinnersSmall.json'
        );
        httpRequest.send();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
                updateData(JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText));
            }
        };
    };

        return (
                    <div id="myGrid" style={{
                            height: 1000,
                            width: 1000,
                        marginLeft: 100
                        }}
                        className="ag-theme-alpine"
                    >
                        <AgGridReact
                            columnDefs={columnData}
                            defaultColDef={defaultColData}
                            suppressRowClickSelection={true}
                            rowSelection={rowSelection}
                            onGridReady={onGridReady}
                            rowData={rowData}
                        />
                    </div>
        );
}
```

I want my first column to have checkbox , clicking on which I should be able to select/unselect rows. With the above code I am able to see checkbox in the first column, when i am clicking on it, it is getting clicked but the state of checkbox is not getting changed in UI and row is also not getting selected. Anything that I am missing here.

I figured out above example works well if we don't use typescript but not working for ag-grid-react + typescript.

Answer (score -1):

False Alarm : some global css for checkbox is restricting me to do that. Fixing the global css to a specific one resolves the issue.